# SAS SQL: Merge consecutive rows with blank date if the next row is different

Tags: sql, sas, proc-sql

I have a table `t1` with fields `activity_name` (integer) and `status_change_dttm` (date):

```
activity_name status_change_dttm
------1------  -------null-------  
------1------  -------null-------  
------1------  18FEB2019:19:16:13  
------2------  -------null-------  
------3------  -------null-------  
------3------  -------null-------  
------3------  -------null-------  
------4------  -------null-------  
------5------  03FEB2019:14:38:52  
------5------  04FEB2019:18:30:52
------5------  14FEB2019:12:00:12
```

The result should look like this:

```
activity_name status_change_dttm   
------1------  18FEB2019:19:16:13  
------2------  -------null-------  
------3------  -------null-------   
------4------  -------null-------  
------5------  03FEB2019:14:38:52  
------5------  04FEB2019:18:30:52  
------5------  14FEB2019:12:00:12
```

So if I have rows with the same `activity_name` and null values in `status_change_dttm` and the next activity doesn't equal to the previous one, I need to merge these rows in one row. If I have rows with null values in `status_change_dttm` and the next row is with the same `activity_name` and `status_change_dttm` is not null, I need to drop only rows with nulls.
**To conclude:**

```
1) IF NULL - NULL - DATE - next activity -> drop nulls  
2) IF NULL - NULL - NULL - next activity -> merge into one row  
3) IF DATE - DATE - DATE - next activity -> no changes  
4) IF one NULL - next activity -> no changes  
5) IF one DATE - next activity -> no changes
```

I guess the key is lag/lead functions, but I don't understand the overall concept. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Hmmm . . . This almost does what you want:

```
select distinct t.activity_name, t.status_change_dttm
from t1 t;
```

However, this will return `NULL` values even when non-`NULL` values exist, such as for 1.  To prevent that:

```
select distinct t.activity_name, t.status_change_dttm
from t1 t
where t.activity_name is not null or
      not exists (select 1
                  from t1 t2
                  where t2.activity_name = t.activity_name and
                        t2.status_change_dttm is not null
                 );
```

Note:  The `select distinct` may not be needed in this case.

Answer (score 0):

A SAS data step solution could be as follows:

```
/* set up data */
data have;
   infile datalines truncover;

   input activity_name      :         8.
         status_change_dttm : datetime20.
   ;

   format status_change_dttm datetime20.;

   datalines;
1 
1 
1 18FEB2019:19:16:13
2 
3 
3 
3 
4 
5 03FEB2019:14:38:52
5 04FEB2019:18:30:52
5 14FEB2019:12:00:12
15 
15 04FEB2019:18:30:52
15 14FEB2019:12:00:12
;


/* process and output */
data want;
   null_count  = 0;
   group_count = 0;

   /* count number of records and nulls for this activity_name group */
   do until(last.activity_name);
      set have;
      by activity_name;

      group_count + 1;

      if missing(status_change_dttm) then
         null_count + 1;
   end;

   /* output data for the same activity_name group */
   do until(last.activity_name);
      set have;
      by activity_name;

      if null_count = 0 then
         output;
      else
         if null_count eq group_count then
         do;
            output;
            /* prevent any more null records being output */
            null_count + 1;
         end;
         else
            if null_count lt group_count and not missing(status_change_dttm) then
               output;
   end;
run;
```